# Return item after dropping second item

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-events

Can we somehow return first dropped item back after dropping second item?

```
  $(".stackDrop").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
    }
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/70x2set8/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
  $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
  $('#launchPad').append($('.card').not($(ui.draggable)))
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfepkb6c/)

Comment: Perfect!! I am impressed by your knowledge!! Thank you!